# Nothing prints out in the console in command line tool Xcode

Tags: swift, barrier

Nothing prints out in the console in command line tool Xcode when I run the following code:

```
import Foundation

class A {
  var someValue = 0

  let concurrentQueue = dispatch_queue_create("queue_for_property", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)

  func increaseValueBy1000() {
    dispatch_barrier_async(concurrentQueue) {
      for _ in 0 ..< 1000 {
        let v = self.someValue + 1
        print(v)
        self.someValue = v
      }
    }
  }
}

let instance1 = A()

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)) {
  instance1.increaseValueBy1000()
}

instance1.increaseValueBy1000()
```

I don't see any print statement in the console.
If I remove barrier line works pretty fine.
What I do wrong in this case why my barriers don't allow to print?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applications – such has command-line programs – which do not already have a "run loop" have to call

```
dispatch_main() // Swift 2
dispatchMain()  // Swift 3
```

in order to use GCD. From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452860-dispatchmain):

> This function "parks" the main thread and waits for blocks to be
>   submitted to the main queue. Applications that call `UIApplicationMain`
>   (iOS), `NSApplicationMain` (Mac OS X), or `CFRunLoopRun` on the main
>   thread must not call `dispatch_main`.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain in what part I should call it?

Comment: @wm.p1us: At the end of your program. See also https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_main.3.html.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! But if I remove barrier I got duplication values but not race condition. Because values are not rewritten.

Comment: i am facing the same problem in my command line tool created in swift language. What needs to be done? the above link is invalid for apple developer forum. Please explain the solution.

Comment: @Tejas: I have added a link to the current documentation.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for your quick response. Can you please explain what changes I need to make to my code. My issue is I created a simple swift package manager app - hello word application and running the executable from Mac terminal by navigating to the executable folder and calling it. It does not print "Hello world" in my terminal window of mac?

Comment: @Tejas: I suggest to ask a separate question. Make sure to provide a [repro] which demonstrates the problem clearly.